# The interval in which $ab+bc+ca$ lies if $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

What is the interval in which $$ab+bc+ca$$ lies if $$a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$.I have considered using the AM-GM inequality. But that's not working. Please provide some advice.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to do the upper bound is to note that $$0\le (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ca)$$ so that $$ab+bc+ca\le a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$

And it is clear that equality is possible only if $a=b=c$. Plugging this in shows that the bound is achieved (which we know generally from compactness).

For the lower bound, as already noted in previous answers $(a+b+c)^2\ge 0$ gives $ab+bc+ca\ge -\frac 12$ with equality when $a+b+c=0$.

Answer (score 5):

We can use Lagrange multipliers. Since the set $\{a^2+b^2+c^2=1\}$ is smooth and compact, the extreme values of $ab+bc+ac$ on it will all occur at local stationary points: that is, when its gradient is parallel to the gradient of $a^2+b^2+c^2$. This means the problem amounts to solving the following system of four equations:
$$
b+c=2\lambda a\\
a+c=2\lambda b\\
a+b = 2 \lambda c\\
a^2+b^2+c^2=1
$$

Adding the first three equations together gives
$$
2(a+b+c)=2\lambda(a+b+c)
$$
and so either $\lambda=1$ or $a+b+c=0$.

If $\lambda=1$, the first three equations say that each of $a,b,c$ is the average of the other two. So they are all equal. Thus $a=b=c=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, in which case $ab+bc+ac=1$.

If $a+b+c=0$, then the first three equations are all guaranteed to be satisfied with $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}$. In this case, $ab+bc+ac=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}=\frac{0-1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$.

As these are the only stationary points, in general we must have $-\frac{1}{2} \leq ab+ac+bc \leq 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$0\le(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=1+2(ab+bc+ca)$

So

$ab+bc+ca\ge-\frac12$

Also when $a=b=c=\frac1{\sqrt3}$, $ab+bc+ca$ attains its maximum,that is $1$.

**To verify the the result**,  we have

Minimum:
$a=\frac1{\sqrt2},b=-\frac1{\sqrt2},c=0$, so
$ab+bc+ca=-\frac12+0+0=-\frac12$

Comment: You mean the maximum?

Comment: Almost there, but you still haven't shown $ab+bc+ca \le 1$. You have merely stated it without any proof.

Comment: Let me have a try of it.

Comment: Mark Bennet has a proof of it. Shall +1 for him.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{u}=(a,b,c)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(b,c,a)$. Then use Cauchy Schwarz inequality $|\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}| \leq ||\mathbf{u}||||\mathbf{v}||=1\cdot1=1$

Comment: The problem with that is that you need to show both ends of the interval are in fact achievable to find the extreme.

Comment: Your Cauchy Schwarz application seems to indicate $-1$ is the lower end of the interval. Really?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\cos A,b=\sin A\cos B,c=\sin A\sin B$

$$S=ab+bc+ca=\cos A\sin A\cos B+\sin^2A\cos B\sin B+\sin A\sin B\cos A$$

$$=\cos A\sin A[\cos B+\sin B]+\sin^2A\cos B\sin B$$

$$2S=\sin2A[\cos B+\sin B]+(1-\cos2A)\cos B\sin B$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin2B}2+\sqrt{(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2}\sin\left[2A+\arctan\dfrac{\cos B\sin B}{\cos B+\sin B}\right]$$

$\implies\dfrac{\sin2B}2-\sqrt{(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2}$
$\le\dfrac{\sin2B}2+\sqrt{(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2}\sin\left[2A+\arctan\dfrac{\cos B\sin B}{\cos B+\sin B}\right]$
$\le\dfrac{\sin2B}2+\sqrt{(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2}$

Now,$(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2=\cdots=\left(\dfrac{\sin2B+2}2\right)^2$

$\implies\dfrac{\sin2B}2-\sqrt{(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2}\le\dfrac{\sin2B}2-\dfrac{\sin2B+2}2=-1$

and $\dfrac{\sin2B}2+\sqrt{(\cos B+\sin B)^2+(\cos B\sin B)^2}\le\dfrac{\sin2B}2+\dfrac{\sin2B+2}2=1+\sin2B\le2$

$$\implies-1\le2S\le2$$

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound:
$$(a+b+c)^2>0$$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)>0$$

$$1+2(ab+bc+ca)>0$$

$$-\frac12<ab+bc+ca$$

The upper bound:

$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(a-c)^2>0$$

$$a^2+b^2-2ab+b^2+c^2-2ac+a^2+c^2-2ac>0$$

$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-ac)>0$$

$$ab+bc+ac<1$$