# Finding the range of $ab+bc+ca$

Tags: functions, inequality

> If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ then find the range of $ab+bc+ca$.

My attempt: We know 
$$ 0\le(a + b+c)^2 $$
$$ 0\le a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca) $$
$$ 0\le1 + 2(ab+bc+ca) $$
$$ -1/2\le ab+bc+ca $$
$$ range = [-1/2 ,\infty) $$
But the answer is $[-1/2 , 1]$. I would like to know how to proceed further.

Comment: $\LaTeX \text { Tip}:$ Use \infty , \frac {a}{b} and \le to obtain $\infty, \frac ab$ and $\le$.

Comment: Also: [The interval in which $ab+bc+ca$ lies if $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1323463/42969).

Answer (score 4):

By Cauchy-Schwartz,
$$ab+bc+ca = \langle(a,b,c), (b,c,a)\rangle \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+c^2+a^2} = a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$ for all real numbers $$x,y,z$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$  a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca) = (a + b + c)^2 $$
(which is **not** $(a^2 + b^2+c^2)^2$).

The points such that $a^2 + b^2+c^2 = 1$ all lie on a sphere of radius $1.$
You can never be more than $1$ unit away from the origin on such a sphere,
so $a \leq 1,$ $b \leq 1,$  and $c \leq 1.$

These three facts already mean that $a + b + c \leq 3,$
and therefore $(a + b + c)^2 \leq 9.$
So you have a (not very large!) upper bound as well as a lower bound.

The question is exactly what the least upper bound is.
Looking at a sphere, it should be clear that the sum $a + b + c$ cannot actually get close to $3.$
You can use various techniques to try to find the maximum of $a + b + c$;
one way is to recognize that it will occur at the point where the sphere
$a^2 + b^2+c^2 = 1$ is tangent to a plane with equation $a + b + c = k.$
In order for $(a,b,c)$ to be the point of tangency, the vector from the origin to
$(a,b,c)$ must be normal to the plane $a + b + c = k,$
and therefore $a = b = c.$
But then $3a^2 = a^2 + b^2+c^2 = 1,$ so $a = \sqrt{\frac13},$
and therefore $b = c = \sqrt{\frac13}$ as well.
From this you can find the maximum value of $(a + b + c)^2.$

---

So that's an answer based on geometric intuition.
But note that Cauchy-Schwartz (used in other answers) gets you this result a lot quicker.